# How to sort by count of events [rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to sort this by count of events?
I tried diffrences ways but it still doesn't work:

```
<tr>
    <% User.all.each  do |user| %> 
    <td> <%= user.name %></td>
    <td> <%= user.events.count %></br></td>
<% end %>
 </tr>
```

And this is a model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it through `counter_cache`

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy,counter_cache: true
end
```

Add a column `events_count` to your users table like this

```
 add_column :users, :events_count, :integer, :default => 0
```

and use it in the view like this

```
<tr>
    <% User.all.each  do |user| %> 
    <td> <%= user.name %></td>
    <td> <%= user.events_count %></br></td> #here
<% end %>
 </tr>
```

I would like to suggest to look into this **[Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)**,but it is old.

Look in to this **[plugin](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture)** And here is an **[example](http://hiteshrawal.blogspot.com/2011/12/rails-counter-cache.html)** how it is done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How does it help to sort ?

Comment: But how to set it in View?

Comment: @ArupRakshit By looking in to this `<%= user.events.count %>`,the OP is actually trying to counter relational objects.So that leads to `counter_cache`